# Is it possible to set a priority to elements in a list?

Tags: python, list

i'm trying to set a priority for each element in my list, here is the code :

```
mylist = []

state0 = [True, 2]
state1 = [False, 2]
state2 = [True, 3]
state3 = [True, 4]
state4 = [False, 3]

mylist.append(state0)
mylist.append(state1)
mylist.append(state2)
mylist.append(state3)
mylist.append(state4)



def function():
    for element, priority in mylist:
        if element is False and ...: # And priority is higher than the others
            
function()
```

The fact here, is that I need to retrieve an element in mylist that is False and its priority is higher than all the elements in mylist.

I don't know if there is a pythonic way to do that.
If you have any idea, i'll take it !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue)

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looing for - https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html

Comment: Thanks, i'm taking a look at that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max` with `key` base numbers, then find the max number and check `if` base max number.

```
from operator import itemgetter
max_num = max(mylist, key=itemgetter(1))[1]
# max(mylist, key=itemgetter(1)) -> [True, 4] 
# [True, 4][1] -> 4

def function(mylist):
    max_num = max(mylist, key=itemgetter(1))[1]
    for element, priority in mylist:
        if element is False and priority > max_num: # And priority is higher than the others
            # Do waht you want
            
function(mylist)
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm gonna try this implementation

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) (remove True's) and [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) by priority, so the first element of the sorted list has a high priority than the other ones:

```
mylist = [[True, 2], [False, 2], [True, 3], [True, 4], [False, 3]]

mylist = filter(lambda x: x[0] == False, mylist)  # Keep all falses
print(
    sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]), reverse=1)[0]
)  # sort by priority
```

Out:

```
[False, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make your priority values negative, you can simply use `min()` to retrieve the element you want.  Or if not, use a custom `key` argument to `min()` or `max()` to make the lowest-value-but-highest-priority element come out first, for example:

```
selected = min(mylist,  key=lambda x:[x[0],-x[1]] )
print(selected is state4)    #  prints True
if selected[0] == False:
    do_something_with( selected )
```

Your question implies you want to process just the one element whose priority is greatest. But if you want to process more, you can also do `mylist.sort( key=... )`  so that *all* the Falsies come out earlier than all the Truthies, in priority order.